# Reconstruct the list of dict in python but the result is not in order

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
list_1 = [{'1': 'name_1', '2': 'name_2', '3': 'name_3',}, 
       {'1': 'age_1', '2': 'age_2' ,'3': 'age_3',}]
```

I want to manipulate this list so that the dicts contain all the attributes for a particular ID. The ID itself must form part of the resulting dict. An example output is shown below:

```
list_2 = [{'id' : '1', 'name' : 'name_1', 'age': 'age_1'},
       {'id' : '2', 'name' : 'name_2', 'age': 'age_2'},
       {'id' : '3', 'name' : 'name_3', 'age': 'age_3'}]
```

Then I did following:

```
>>> list_2=[{'id':x,'name':list_1[0][x],'age':list_1[1][x]} for x in list_1[0].keys()]
```

Then it gives:

```
>>> list_2
    [{'age': 'age_1', 'id': '1', 'name': 'name_1'}, 
     {'age': 'age_3', 'id': '3', 'name': 'name_3'}, 
     {'age': 'age_2', 'id': '2', 'name': 'name_2'}]
```

But I don't understand why 'id' is showing in the second position while 'age' showing first?

I tried other ways but the result is the same. Any one can help to figure it out?

Comment: I think this is quite the duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1867861/42346

Comment: python dictionaries has no order. you must you ordered dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the order, you should use an [ordered dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). Using your sample:

```
new_list = [OrderedDict([('id', x), ('name', list_1[0][x]), ('age', list_1[1][x])]) for x in list_1[0].keys()]
```

Printing the ordered list...

```
for d in new_list:                                                                                            
    print(d[name], d[age])
```

> name_1 age_1
>
> name_3 age_3
>
> name_2 age_2

Answer (score 0):

Try using an OrderedDict:

```
list_1 = [collections.OrderedDict([('1','name_1'), ('2', 'name_2'), ('3', 'name_3')]),
        collections.OrderedDict([('1','age_1'),('2','age_2'),('3', 'age_3')])]

list_2=[collections.OrderedDict([('id',x), ('name',list_1[0][x]), ('age', list_1[1][x])]) 
        for x in list_1[0].keys()]
```

This is more likely to preserve the order you want.  I am still new to Python, so this may not be super Pythonic, but I think it will work.

output -

```
In [24]: list( list_2[0].keys() )
Out[24]: ['id', 'name', 'age']
```

Docs:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Examples:
https://pymotw.com/2/collections/ordereddict.html

Getting the constructors right:
[Right way to initialize an OrderedDict using its constructor such that it retains order of initial data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25480089/initializing-an-ordereddict-using-its-constructor)