# Pandas: create dataframe without auto ordering column names alphabetically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am creating an initial pandas dataframe to store results generated from other codes: e.g.

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'date': datelist, 'total': [0]*len(datelist), 
                       'TT': [0]*len(datelist)})
```

with `datelist` a predefined list. Then other codes will output some number for `total` and `TT` for each `date`, which I will store in the `result` dataframe.

So I want the first column to be `date`, second `total` and third `TT`. However, pandas will automatically reorder it alphabetically to `TT`, `date`, `total` at creation. While I can manually reorder this again afterwards, I wonder if there is an easier way to achieve this in one step.

I figured I can also do

```
result = pd.DataFrame(np.transpose([datelist, [0]*l, [0]*l]),
                      columns = ['date', 'total', 'TT'])
```

but it somehow also looks tedious. Any other suggestions?

Comment: if I use `df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['b','a'])` it will retiain the order, but if I use `df = pd.DataFrame(columns =  {'b','a'})`, the order of column names will be changed to `'a' 'b'`, any reason behind this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can pass the (correctly ordered) list of column as parameter to the constructor or use an OrderedDict:

```
# option 1:
result = pd.DataFrame({'date': datelist, 'total': [0]*len(datelist), 
                   'TT': [0]*len(datelist)}, columns=['date', 'total', 'TT'])

# option 2:
od = collections.OrderedDict()
od['date'] = datelist
od['total'] = [0]*len(datelist)
od['TT'] = [0]*len(datelist)
result = pd.DataFrame(od)
```

Comment: I was going to suggest an `OrderedDict` but it doesn't work, it just gets cast to a `dict` probably. I didn't get reproducible order with it.

Comment: It should work, pandas explicitly checks for it: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L397

Comment: Haha, you're right, I completely screwed up my `OrderedDict` definition:) Thanks, and sorry.

Comment: As the other answer suggested, if do `result = pd.DataFrame({'date': datelist, 'total': [0]*len(datelist), 'TT': [0]*len(datelist)}, columns=['date', 'total', 'TT'])`, as in your first line, then it already seems to give the right order, so the rest is not necessary? Or am I missing something?

Comment: If I simply copy and paste all your code, it actually only gave me a dataframe with one column `date`.

Comment: Those were meant as two alternatives. I've clarified it now.

Comment: I see! So it seems like I need to either explicitly add the `column` argument in `DataFrame` or create an OrderedDict and insert each component separately. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. You could also initialize the OrderedDict this way, but I consider it less readable:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/25480206/3257586

Comment: Additional warning: if you have a dict of dicts, they *both* need to be OrderedDict (I just spent 10 minutes trying to understand why it wasn't working for me... ^_^; )

Comment: I am creating a dataframe from Django table. Though functionalIy there is no issue, but I find that the columns are re-ordered (I think in alphabetical order). This sometimes causes heartburn when the data is to displayed. Can this ordering "functionality" be **stopped**?

Answer (score 3):

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'date': [23,24], 'total': 0,
                       'TT': 0},columns=['date','total','TT'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use pandas >= 0.23 in combination with Python >= 3.6.

`result = pd.DataFrame({'date': datelist, 
                        'total': [0]*len(datelist), 
                        'TT': [0]*len(datelist)})`

retains the dict's insertion order when creating a DataFrame (or Series) from a dict when using pandas v0.23.0 in combination with Python3.6.

See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.0/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0230-api-breaking-dict-insertion-order.

Comment: There is one caveat, it works fine for a `dict` of `list`s, but not for a `list` of `dict`s. Even if all the dicts have the same insertion order, the columns are still sorted alphabetically. (Tested with `pandas` 0.24.2 and Python 3.7)