# How to stop pandas from auto-ordering columns in dataframe alphabetically?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary that I want to turn into a dataframe. When I use

```
pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
```

It modifies the order of the columns to be in alphabetical order. I want the order to be as input.

There is a problem almost exactly like this here:

[Pandas: create dataframe without auto ordering column names alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39862053/pandas-create-dataframe-without-auto-ordering-column-names-alphabetically)

The accepted answer has two solutions. The first solution in my case I do not think would work or would at least be tedious and not as readable because my dictionary is nested and much longer than his.

The second solution involves using `collections.OrderedDict` to create an ordered dict which is then converted into a dataframe. This supposedly should fix the problem but it does not for me. The dataframe is still ordered alphabetically. I think it may have to do with the fact that my dictionary is nested. I tried using `collections.OrderedDict` on all nested dicts and it still did not work. Well it worked, but did not change my sorted column issue. Here is my code:

```
my_dict = collections.OrderedDict()
code code code
for fname in os.listdir(myfile)
labels = collections.OrderedDict({A : 1, C : 2, B : 3, etc})
my_dict.update({fname : labels})
```

Obviously this is very simplified, but it shows the general idea. I make an empty ordered dictionary, then sort through a file and collect labels with values and store them in an ordered dictionary, then update the my_dict with the fname and labels ordered dict.

The dataframe that is output when I use `pd.DataFrame(my_dict).T` orders the columns (e.g. A,C,B) in alphabetical order. I would like it to be in input order.

If you know why my dataframe is still auto-sorting alphabetically or of another way to sort this please let me know!

Comment: I later versions of python (>= 3.6), the order of keys in a vanilla python dict is remembered. So something like `pandas.DataFrame(dict(a=[1], d=[2],c=[3]))` will have a columns array ['a','d','c']. Is using a more recent version of python an option?

Comment: No it is not and I probably could do `pandas.DataFrame(my_dict(a=[1], d=[2], etc)' However, I would like to not have to type out all of it since I have a ton of columns. I will try it though and use it for now unless somebody knows a different solution.

Comment: I have the exact same issue and it is super annoying as the console output in new order does not make any sense at all. Will post if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas will not automatically re-order columns if the arguments `axis=1` and `sort=False` are used.

Here is an example of appending a dataframe `df` (read from spreadsheet) to an empty dataframe `f` while preserving the original column order:

`f = f.append(df, axis=1, ignore_index=False, sort=False)`

`ignore_index=False` preserves the labels of the original columns.