# How to insert an ordered dict to mongodb using pymongo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo

I'm using python 3.5.2 and pymongo while trying to store a dict to mongodb

```
 data = {'A':1,'B':2,'C':3}
 test = {'A':data['A'], 'B':data['B'], 'C':data['C']}
 x = mycol.insert_one(test) #mycol is the name of my collection
```

But the order of the dict is not preserved while inserting the document into the DB. When i run

```
print(mycol.find_one())
```

I get

```
{'A':1, 'C':3, _id': ObjectId('xxxxxx10f389f63bf0c8bfba'), 'B':2}
```

instead of

```
{ _id': ObjectId('xxxxxx10f389f63bf0c8bfba'), 'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3}
```

But i was able to preserve the order when i ran it on a system with python 3.6.2. 
Is the version of python the issue or can i fix it on python 3.5.2 itself?

Comment: have you tried using .insert(test) instead in the older version of python?

Comment: Yep tried that, same result; order is getting messed up

Comment: Consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25480089/right-way-to-initialize-an-ordereddict-using-its-constructor-such-that-it-retain

Comment: @JanneKarila I actually can't use a list like that while inserting documents to mongodb. I've updated my post and removed the OrederedDict. 
The problem still persists on my system but the other system still prints it in the order mentioned