# How can I get data with order in python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddict

I want to get my keys in my order. But, it doesn't work with dictionary and Collections.OrderedDict.

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

data = OrderedDict({
  "Name1": "value1",
  "Name2": "value2"
})

for key in data.keys():
  print(key)
```

This code shows that `Name3 Name4 ...`. It doesn't have any order. My data doesn't have alphabetical order in keys, and I must get the keys in my order.

I found that dictionary is not designed with order. Then, what structures can I use with key and value pair? Or there is any way to use dictionary in custom order? (input order..?)

Comment: what you want is an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: He's using an `OrderedDict` @Nullman (at least what he wrote).

Comment: Your code snippet works as expected for me (using CPython 3.7)

Comment: you might want to try a different way of initialising the `OrderedDict`: For example, use: `OrderedDict(name1="value1", name2="value2")`. See also [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25480089/right-way-to-initialize-an-ordereddict-using-its-constructor-such-that-it-retain]).

Comment: This problem makes me crazy.. It works sometimes and it doesn't work sometimes. There is no process except that. I don't know why ordered dict working in crazy..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the structure of your ordered dictionary from this

```
data = OrderedDict({
  "Name1": "value1",
  "Name2": "value2",
  ...
})
```

to this

```
data = OrderedDict([('Name1', 'value1'), ('Name2', 'Value2')])
```

Comment: to add to your answer, the reason you need to do this is because you are first creating a regular dict, which is unordered, and then turning it into an ordrered dict which will retain THE WRONG ORDER from the regular dict you made

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: Use Python 3.7 or above.

---

[`dict`s in Python 3.7 and above are always ordered](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict). This applies to all sorts of iterations:

> **Dictionaries preserve insertion order.** Note that updating a key does not affect the order. Keys added after deletion are inserted at the end.
>
> Changed in version 3.7: Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order.

This [also applies to the `popitem()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem):

> Changed in version 3.7: **LIFO order is now guaranteed.** In prior versions, popitem() would return an arbitrary key/value pair.
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem